# I'm trying to make a sorting function in Vue and Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Now i have two buttons that work but I want to have it when you click on the TableHead it should change to most stock on top and when clicked again to least stock on top.

I have made a single click event and double click event which works but is not user friendly.

**TableHead**

```
<th scope="col" class="px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 cursor-pointer" @click="sortBy='stockUp'" @dblclick="sortBy='stockDown'">
 Stock
</th>
```

**Variable I use to see what sorting the user wants**

```
const sortBy = ref('priceDown')
```

**My sorting function**

```
watchEffect(() => {
  if (sortBy.value === 'etaDown') {
    suppliers.value.sort((p1, p2) => (p1.space?.computedDeliveryTimestamps?.reduce((a, b) => a + b) ?? 0) - (p2.space?.computedDeliveryTimestamps?.reduce((a, b) => a + b) ?? 0))
  } else if (sortBy.value === 'etaUp') {
    suppliers.value.sort((p2, p1) => (p1.space?.computedDeliveryTimestamps?.reduce((a, b) => a + b) ?? 0) - (p2.space?.computedDeliveryTimestamps?.reduce((a, b) => a + b) ?? 0))
  } else if (sortBy.value === 'stockDown') {
    suppliers.value.sort((p1, p2) => (p1.stocks?.map(s => s.quantity).reduce((a, b) => a + b) ?? 0) - (p2.stocks?.map(s => s.quantity).reduce((a, b) => a + b) ?? 0))
  } else if (sortBy.value === 'stockUp') {
    suppliers.value.sort((p2, p1) => (p1.stocks?.map(s => s.quantity).reduce((a, b) => a + b) ?? 0) - (p2.stocks?.map(s => s.quantity).reduce((a, b) => a + b) ?? 0))
  } else if (sortBy.value === 'priceDown') {
    suppliers.value.sort((p1, p2) => (p1.prices?.map(s => s.price).reduce((a, b) => a + b) ?? 0) - (p2.prices?.map(s => s.price).reduce((a, b) => a + b) ?? 0))
  } else if (sortBy.value === 'priceUp') {
    suppliers.value.sort((p2, p1) => (p1.prices?.map(s => s.price).reduce((a, b) => a + b) ?? 0) - (p2.prices?.map(s => s.price).reduce((a, b) => a + b) ?? 0))
  }
})
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I do not know vue.js , but all you need is to create another variable for example : 
`let sorting = true` then when you press the button always change the variable 
`sorting !=sorting; ` . And if is, for example, true you go decrement and false you go increment.

Comment: Thanks @MuhametSmaili that does work. The problem i'm currently facing is when I have multiple sorting options, only the one that gets declared first in my case ETA works.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this to work without creating another variable.

```
<th scope="col" class="px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 cursor-pointer" @click="sortBy = sortBy === 'stockUp' ? 'stockDown' : 'stockUp'">
     Stock
</th>
```